# random.seed() does not work with np.random.choice()

Tags: python, numpy, random

So i'm trying to generate a list of numbers with desired probability; the problem is that `random.seed()` does not work in this case.

```
M_NumDependent = []

for i in range(61729):
    random.seed(2020)
    n = np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 4), p=[0.44, 0.21, 0.23, 0.12])
    M_NumDependent.append(n)
print(M_NumDependent)
```

the desired output should be the same if the `random.seed()` works, but the output is different everytime i run it. Does anyone know if there's a function does the similar job of `seed()` for `np.random.choice()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`numpy` uses its own pseudo random generator. You can seed the Numpy random generator with [**`np.random.seed(…)`** <sup>[numpy-doc]</sup>](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html#numpy.random.seed):

```
np.random.seed(2020)
```

For example:

```
>>> np.random.seed(2020)
>>> np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 4), p=[0.44, 0.21, 0.23, 0.12])
3
>>> np.random.seed(2020)
>>> np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 4), p=[0.44, 0.21, 0.23, 0.12])
3
>>> np.random.seed(2020)
>>> np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 4), p=[0.44, 0.21, 0.23, 0.12])
3
>>> np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 4), p=[0.44, 0.21, 0.23, 0.12])
2
```

As you can see we each time pick `3` whereas if we do *not* seed the random generator, `2` is the next item after `3`.

Answer (score 5):

You are accidentally setting [`random.random.seed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) instead of [`numpy.random.seed()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html).

---

Instead of

```
random.seed(2020)
```

use

```
import numpy as np 


np.random.seed(2020)
```

and your results will always be reproducible.

Comment: I think you mean `random.seed()` instead of `random.random.seed()` ?